# Does there exist a function $f$ holomorphic in the punctured disk $\{0<|z|<1\}$ such that $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{f(z)^2}{z^3}=1?$

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a function $f$ holomorphic in the punctured disk $\{0<|z|<1\}$ such that 
$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{f(z)^2}{z^3}=1?$$

Attempt: Write $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ so that
$$\frac{f(z)^2}{z^3} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} b_n z^{n-3}.$$
where $b_n = \sum_{j=0}^{n} a_j a_{n-j}$.
Then we just need $b_3 =1?$

Comment: $f^2(z)/z^3$ is analytic on the punctured disc and due to the limit it has a removable singularity at $z=0$. Therefore there is an analytic  function $g(z)$ such that $f^2(z)=z^3g(z)$ and $g(0)=1$. So, $f^2$ has a zero of order exactly $3$ at $z=0$. So, $f$ has a zero at $z=0$. If $m$ is the order of the zero of $f$, then $2m$ is the order of the zero of $f^2$ at $z=0$. Since $3$ is not even, then there is no such function.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ must have a removable singularity at $0$, which when removed becomes a zero. But there's no such thing as a zero of order $3/2$.  It's either $1$ or $\ge 2$, neither of which would produce the limit you want.